# Autohotkey shortcut remapping ^UP:: !UP

Tags: windows, mapping, autohotkey, explorer

I am trying to turn the Shortcut `Ctrl+Arrow Up` into `Alt+Arrow up` by `Autohotkey`, simple.

Reason is, when navigating in the Explorer (Win 10) I like to move one Folder level back towards root as if i would press Alt+Arrow Up but by pressing `Ctrl+Arrow Up`.

I have tried all possible combinations until I could make it work, however a new Explorer window opens, so the result is not exactly the same as when I press `Alt+Arrow Up`.

This was my first idea, which does not do anything at all.

```
^UP:: !Up
```

After tweaking around i found out this works but it opens a new Explorer window instead of remaining in the same window and only moving one level back.

```
^Up::SendInput,!{Up}
```

Spend more than an hour over this using google, forums and trying out every possible combination, how hard can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close, Baka:

```
^Up::Send !{Up}
```

Now AutoHotKey will print Alt+ArrowUp instead of CTRL+ArrowUp.

Consider using

```
^Up::
IfWinActive, Windows Explorer;
Send !{Up}
return
```

to apply for windows named 'Windows Explorer' only.

Comment: Fantastic, just what i was looking for, Thank You so much John! :-)

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. Please vote/mark this answer, ty :-)